# Response from postgres r2db taking lot of time leading to connection time out

Tags: java, postgresql, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

We are using spring boot(2.3.1) reactive programing in our project. DB used is r2dbc-postgres (0.8.7). we are unable to find out the root cause why  the apis  written using reactive stops responding once it connects to DB.

For example in the following code:

```
 @Autowired
 PlanPackageCurrencyPriceRepository planPackageCurrencyPriceRepository;
    
  public Mono<Object> viewBySkuCodeAndCountryCode(String skuCode, String countryCode) {
        Mono<PlanPackageCurrencyPrice> planPackagePriceInfo = planPackageCurrencyPriceRepository
                .findBySkuCodeAndCountryCode(skuCode, countryCode);
        return planPackagePriceInfo.map(planInfo -> {
            PlanPackageCurrencyPriceDTO currencyPriceDTO = PlanPackageCurrencyPriceDTO.builder()
                    .skuCode(planInfo.getSkuCode())
                    .countryCode(planInfo.getCountryCode())
                    .currencyCode(planInfo.getCurrencyCode())
                    .price(planInfo.getPrice())
                    .status(planInfo.getStatus())
                    .build();
            if(planInfo.getStatus() == Status.ACTIVE) {
                final Mono<Boolean> monovalue = redisTemplate.opsForHash().put("getplanpackagecurrencycodeprice",
                        skuCode + countryCode, currencyPriceDTO);
                logger.info(REDIS_VALUE, monovalue.subscribe(System.out::println));
                return currencyPriceDTO;
            } else {
                logger.debug(serviceName.concat(LoggerConstants.PLAN_PACKAGE_GROUP_INFO_VIEW_DEBUG_LOG)
                        .concat(" No items found for Plan/Package Group Info for the  sku code {} "), skuCode);
                throw new CustomException("VIEW_ERRORMESSAGE", HttpStatus.MULTI_STATUS, 10006);
            }
        });
    }
```

when a query is made to DB using planPackageCurrencyPriceRepository, The logs stops at this query, following is the response seen right before time out

```
2021-03-07 10:52:47.427 DEBUG 1 --- [tor-tcp-epoll-4] o.s.d.r.c.R2dbcTransactionManager        : Acquired Connection [MonoRetry] for R2DBC transaction
2021-03-07 10:52:47.427 DEBUG 1 --- [tor-tcp-epoll-4] o.s.d.r.c.R2dbcTransactionManager        : Switching R2DBC Connection [PooledConnection[PostgresqlConnection{client=io.r2dbc.postgresql.client.ReactorNettyClient@7d1a251f, codecs=io.r2dbc.postgresql.codec.DefaultCodecs@7925be64}]] to manual commit
```

given some time. The API responds with error saying **connection time out**.
But then it works fine if we restart our docker container.Then the same behaviour is observed after some time. We are not able to find solution for this intermittent behaviour.

Following is the DB configuration used:

```
@Configuration
@EnableR2dbcRepositories(basePackages = "com.crm.smsauth.postgresrepo")
public class DatabaseConfig extends AbstractR2dbcConfiguration {

    @Value("${postgres.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${postgres.protocol}")
    private String protocol;

    @Value("${postgres.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${postgres.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${postgres.database}")
    private String database;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {

        final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = ConnectionFactories.get(ConnectionFactoryOptions.builder()
                .option(ConnectionFactoryOptions.DRIVER, "pool")
                .option(ConnectionFactoryOptions.PROTOCOL, protocol)
                .option(ConnectionFactoryOptions.HOST, host)
                .option(ConnectionFactoryOptions.USER, username)
                .option(ConnectionFactoryOptions.PASSWORD, password)
                .option(ConnectionFactoryOptions.DATABASE, database)
                .option(MAX_SIZE, 1000)
                .option(INITIAL_SIZE, 1)
                .build());
        return connectionFactory;    
    }
    
    @Bean
    ReactiveTransactionManager transactionManager(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new R2dbcTransactionManager(connectionFactory);
    }
}
```

Please let me know if the issue is with the way reactive code is written or in the DB configuration.

EDIT 2:

Postgres logs :  The DB name is planPackage.

```
2021-03-07 16:26:47.389 IST [24368] postgres@planpackage LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection timed out
```

The timestamps of both the logs doesn't match because, our deployment vm has a timezone set to GMT, But the postgres one is IST.

Comment: and the database logs?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [CONNECT_TIMEOUT](https://r2dbc.io/spec/0.8.0.RELEASE/api/io/r2dbc/spi/ConnectionFactoryOptions.html#CONNECT_TIMEOUT) option? Does increasing this value nullify the problem at some threshold?

Comment: @AlexanderKatsenelenbogen, when the timeout was increased , the api would wait that minutes long and throw same connection time out error.